# Boolean modifier difference not working while others boolean do

Tags: modifiers

my question is quite simple but i did'nt understand while surfing on the internet how could I solve it :

I have some shapes : [image]

Now, I want to cut the circle shape in the gear-like one.
this doesn't work, it works if I use union or intersect but difference doesn't

I hope you can solve my problem and i would be really thanksful if you do !

Comment: Are that curves?

Comment: I think the objects involved in boolean operations must have a volume and not be planes or curves in order to work properly.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer, but I tried extruding them vertically and then, the boolean difference did not work.

I think (as i saw it on the internet) that it may be a question of duplicated nodes but don't know how to solve it